# Sending HTML report as an attachment to mail in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, email-attachments, jenkins-email-ext

I am new to Jenkins. As of now I have added email notification plugin. So once my test is completed now I am getting an email with Build log.

If I want to send Load runner HTML analysis report to mail in the same, what is the procedure?

Can anyone help me here ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible and it's pretty simple.

Download EmailExt plug-in (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)

Then you can use the Pipeline Syntax to easily create it.

However, here's an example your can see as a reference to what you need.

```
emailext attachmentsPattern: '**/*.html', body: 'Body here', subject: 'Subject here', to: 'mail@gmail.com, mail2@gmail.com, mail3@gmail.com'
```

attachmentsPattern uses Ant File Syntax (http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but i'm using https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin
to generate html report from the jenkins workspace ( pwd() )

```
 stage('sysdig report'){
    publishHTML(target: [
        allowMissing         : true,
        alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
        keepAll              : true,
        reportDir            : "${workspace}/",
        reportFiles          : "sysdig-report.html",
        reportName           : "sysdig-report"
    ])
```

You should be able to send the file after.

Comment: i am able to generate but need a procedure to send an attchment via email